# Pure Javascript | add class to <li> elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to add class for `<li>` elements on click event. If I click on the first element it should to get class "current-tab" and others `<li>` elements should not contain that class and etc. 
 Here is some HTML code:

```
<nav class="interest-nav">
  <ul id="interest-ul">
     <li><a href="#box1">Fashion</a></li>
     <li><a href="#box2">Movies</a></li>
     <li><a href="#box3">TV</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and Javascript code:

```
var navUl = document.getElementById('interest-ul').getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var y = 0; y < navUl.length; y++) {
    navUl[y].addEventListener('click', checkLi);
}

function checkLi() {
    if (navUl.className === '') {
        navUl.className = 'current-tab';
    } else {
        navUl.className = '';
    }
}
```

Thank you for your attention and for your help!

Comment: `navUl` is an array and not a `HTMLElement`

Comment: navUl.classList.add('current-tab'); https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp also you may want to pass this into the checkLi event callback as navUl is an array

Comment: With pure Javascript not jQuery...

Comment: classList is pure javascript not jquery

Comment: no, no, it was addressed to @Pete 
 Nevermind :)

Comment: @DanielHarrison both duplicates are pointing at pure js questions - what about both of those titles makes you think I am talking about jQuery?  Any way, it is expected you do research before asking a question here - a simple search for your title brings back a whole host of solutions.  Please try using a little more effort in future

Comment: @Pete ok, thanks by the way. I am a novice at programming. So sometimes I don't know how to syntactically correct write code.

Comment: Ok, that's fine but you should state that in your question - you haven't actually said what's wrong with your code, you have just said you are trying to add a class to li elements - if your code is not working, then you should state what part of it is not working and give any error messages you may be receiving, or at the very least create a working snippet so we can see your code not working

Comment: @Pete ok, got it. Thanks for advice and for help!

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to set the class on an array. You could simplify this script by adding an event listener to the list itself and then work with the event target.

```js
var navUl = document.getElementById( 'interest-ul' );
navUl.addEventListener( 'click', checkLi );

function checkLi( event ) {
  // Just for testing... remove the following line:
  console.log( 'clicked on', event.target.tagName );
  // Only apply our actions if we really clicked on the link.
  if ( event.target.tagName === 'A' ) {
    navUl.querySelectorAll( 'li' ).forEach( el => el.classList.remove( 'current-tab' ) );
    event.target.parentNode.classList.add( 'current-tab' );
  }
}
```

```css
.current-tab {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<nav class="interest-nav">
  <ul id="interest-ul">
    <li><a href="#box1">Fashion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box2">Movies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box3">TV</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explanations!

Comment: Could you please explain what "A" means in 'event.target.tagName === 'A''?

Comment: Sure... so basically the `event.target` is the element I clicked on. To make sure to only set the active state when clicked on an actual link, we check the `tagName`. And I guess due to legacy stuff `event.target.tagName` holds the tag name in capital letters: `A`. If we would have clicked outside of an `<a>` tag but within the `<ul>` we might either get an `UL` for `<ul>` or `LI` for `<li>`. I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: I updated my answer that actually prints the clicked `tagName`

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it :)

Comment: Take care of CamelCase in classList.

Comment: Just a reminder for people like me who always write in small letters. You did it correct, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to the function. Inside the function you can first remove the *class* from the all elements and add the *class* only to the current element.

**Please Note:** You can also use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which allows valid [`CSS selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) as parameters.

```js
var navUl = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#interest-ul > li'));
for (var y = 0; y < navUl.length; y++) {
    navUl[y].addEventListener('click', function(){checkLi(this)});
}

function checkLi(current) {
  navUl.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('current-tab'));
  current.classList.add('current-tab');
}
```

```css
.current-tab{
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<nav class="interest-nav">
   <ul id="interest-ul">
      <li><a href="#box1">Fashion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#box2">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#box3">TV</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

You can also use [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

```js
var navUl = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#interest-ul > li'));
for (var y = 0; y < navUl.length; y++) {
  navUl[y].addEventListener('click', checkLi);
}

function checkLi(event) {
  navUl.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('current-tab'));
  event.currentTarget.classList.add('current-tab');
}
```

```css
.current-tab{
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<nav class="interest-nav">
   <ul id="interest-ul">
      <li><a href="#box1">Fashion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#box2">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#box3">TV</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var navUl = document.getElementById('interest-ul').getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var y = 0; y < navUl.length; y++) {
  navUl[y].addEventListener('click', checkLi);
}

function checkLi(ev) {
  document.querySelector('.current-tab').classList.remove('current-tab');

  ev.target.classList.add('current-tab');
}
```

```css
.current-tab {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="interest-nav">
  <ul id="interest-ul">
    <li><a href="#box1" class="current-tab">Fashion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box2">Movies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box3">TV</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are trying to set class to the whole collection (`navUl.className = 'current-tab';`). But you should iterate elements.

Second thing is about loops. Cache your length in variable before loop, it will be a bit faster.

```
var navUl = document.getElementById('interest-ul').getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var y = 0, l = navUl.length; y < l; y++) {
    navUl[y].addEventListener('click', checkLi);
}

function checkLi() {
    for (var y = 0, l = navUl.length; y < l; y++) {
        navUl[y].classList.remove('current-tab');
    }
    this.classList.add('current-tab');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it! It works!

Comment: note that you can improve this code. it is far from perfect :)

Comment: Ok, sure! But anyway - thanks!